How do you write a convincing extrovert as the POV character?
One of the main characters in my story is an extrovert: people-loving (and pleasing), gung-ho cheerful attitude, and socially intelligent. She's a foil to the other main character, an introvert who doesn't like starting any kind of personal relationship. Both have POVs in the book.
My issue is that, whenever I try to write the extroverted character, she either ends up sounding like Mickey Mouse ("c'mon guys, let's go do this fun thing together and have fun! together!) or going on these long monologues about random stuff. In other words, her voice doesn't sound at all natural.
How can I fix that? And are there any resources/fictional characters you recommend I check out?

Geese Leadership

Geese leadership is a buzzword at office management seminars describing a team dynamic where there is a constant flow of communication and positive encouragement shared between the group (in contrast to a top-down boss/employee dynamic).
Geese fly in a V-formation that provides lift, allowing a flock to fly much higher and farther than one bird could fly alone. Aerodynamics reenforce the formation, each will immediately feel when they are out of wing-alignment because they have to work harder. When the lead goose gets tired it will fall back and another will take the position.
Meanwhile the geese are constantly signaling to each other (especially when power-flying, not so much when gliding) so no one gets left behind and the birds further up the formation know the state of the birds further back. Geese Leadership philosophy calls this 'encouragement', but as an evolutionary trait it becomes obvious why they need to 'honk' and loudly.
Your extrovert character may have a geese leadership personality, or may have grown up in a community that used this communication style. It is 'normal' for her to confirm her state to the group, and she expects to hear the same back. Not getting that reenforcement is a sign something is wrong. She will have to work harder to compensate, like a goose forced to fly alone without the benefit of a wing-formation.
What she talks about, isn't what she's talking about

Whenever I try to write the extroverted character, she either ends up
sounding like Mickey Mouse ("c'mon guys, let's go do this fun thing
together and have fun! together!) or going on these long monologues
about random stuff.

This is a perfect description of an extrovert from the POV of an introvert. An introvert can see the behavior, see how others respond positively (apparently), and thus the extrovert has 'social intelligence' that is beyond the introvert's understanding.
You already have an instinct for this character's voice and how she seems from the outside. As author, you just need to connect that behavior to her wants and needs, so this behavior always feels story-relevant.
On the surface, what she says will be her secondary motive, the motive of all extroverts: attempting to align the group.
But she has a hidden, personal motive which you communicate to the reader through subtext. For readers, her superficial talk is always leading or revealing, never filler.
Introverts just need encouragement
She's not just talking to fill the empty space. She is actively trying to 'make every situation better' according to her understanding of the world.
If she weren't talking, it would be because she is depressed or the situation is dire.... But some people aren't good at conversation, so she feels the urge to 'help' them. She will talk to put them at ease until they are comfortable. She's not going to give up on them just because they are socially awkward.
Or, she would like to move to the next level, but she's waiting for others to return the right signals. When they don't, she is stuck repeating superficial encouragement, and accepting the communication cues they do return.
Like the introvert, she can witness their behavior but she cannot understand it – it's just not natural. Since she can't fix the person she will fix the situation. She gives positive signals and keeps up the chatter. Even if they complain, it would be like the sullen complaint of a child – it doesn't need to be respected.
This blindspot is more a handicap than a character flaw because she will not see it as a 'me' problem, it is a 'them' problem – reenforced when she comes across another extrovert who knows how communication is suppose to work. Suddenly she has a skills and can charm strangers.
(Character flaws are something the story works to correct, while handicaps are character limitations that the story doesn't expect to change.)
Emma, extrovert as a flaw
Jane Austen's Emma is 'handsome, clever, and rich'. She has no reason for introspection because she has no wants or flaws according to Emma, setting up a hubris arc.
When Emma's friendship status quo is broken, rather than work through her feelings she externalizes this conflict and starts imposing her soft-power onto others. The book avoids examining why Emma needs to control since Emma herself has no awareness of vulnerability. (It is in the text, but never acknowledged by the story.)
Her manipulations are comedic beats in her own character growth arc, mostly flighty plans that derail others and are ultimately wrong or embarrassing. What keeps her likable is that she takes her lumps and adapts to her mistakes, reformulating her plan rather than give up. By the end of the story Emma has mellowed and stops manipulating, but it coincides with a new relationship status quo. It's ambiguous whether she's morally changed or just occupied with her new life.
I offer Emma as an extrovert to the extreme. She controls the conversation because she is spinning a story that works to her favor. She goes into crisis mode and puts her own emotional needs first – which is triggered by abandonment issues: a feedback loop that requires external confirmation and validation. But she doesn't internalize anything, all conflicts can be persuaded because she is witty and charismatic and charming. But she has an ulterior selfish motive for being friends in the first place – a complex motive she's never going to acknowledge.

What you describe sounds like a typical case of wanting to write something you are unfamiliar with. Obviously you aren't extroverted yourself and have no extroverted friends. Your image of extroversion is vague and influenced by hearsay.
What you need to do is what everyone needs to do who wants to write about something they don't know: research.
The "problem" with research when it comes to people and their personalities is that you cannot simply read one book or what a few YouTube videos. You can do that with learning enough about an being a nurse or life in Lagos to write about an occupation or a foreign place convincingly. But people are different.
Most of your readers will have lived among people all their lives and have a very good understanding of human personalities. They will easily notice when your characters seem inconsistent or unnatural – just like you did yourself.
So to learn about different kinds of people, you have to live among them. Good writers of convincing characters aren't recluses. They go out and meet and observe people in real life. You cannot learn about people from books.
So where can you encounter and learn about extroverts? Extroverts draw energy from social interactions, so they seek out situations where they can make social connections and engage with groups:

at all kinds of gatherings, from parties to fairs
team sports
performing arts
volunteer work and political activism
and so on (do your own research to find more places to find extroverts)

What you need to do is partake in these activities and observe the people there. Meet extroverts and get to know them.
